# Are materials even made in Blender?

Tags: texturing, materials

First of all, thank you for taking the time. I'm still new and this question might be silly. Anyways, in every tutorial I see, the materials used to texture the object are "just" downloaded. So, I am asking myself: **Do you even make materials in Blender?** Or are you just downloading or creating them in another program? If yes, then what is the "Shading" Tab used for and in which program do you make those textures? Maybe "Materialize"  or "Substance Designer"?

**Edit**: Since the question seemed to be unclear (sorry about that), here's some clarification: My question was if you even create materials (like a cookie with holes and cracks and more) using nodes in blender, or if you're creating them in another program.

Comment: In the Edit:: Preferences, you can enable the Blender Cloud where you can peruse and download many materials https://cloud.blender.org/blog/introducing-blender-cloud-texture-library-add-on/ so unlike 3ds Max that installs a library of textures, in blender you download them one by one as needed.

Comment: This is a very general question, but the answer is that people do both.  You can download materials, and even pay for them from some sites, or you can create your own materials.  Look on youtube for tutorials on blender procedural materials for some examples of how people create their own.

Comment: of course you make your materials in Blender

Comment: i would say: it depends... if you know your size of your objects will never change, you can use images/textures, which are not procedural. But if the size could change (like in animations or because of clients who change their mind) procedural materials make sense because their quality is always perfect (and not size dependent)...and once you know how the shader nodes work and what they can do - you will LOVE to make materials with it ;) because possibilities are amazing. e.g: https://shorturl.at/lxGM9 -> the text animation is just a material!

Comment: do you think it's a question about textures (i.e. bitmap image that are used in Image Texture nodes)?

Comment: Thank you all very much!

Comment: Blender is very good for procedural materials. For textures, in the sense of bitmap images, you can paint them in the Image Editor (or even in the 3D view) but it's not as powerful as Substance or this kind of software

Comment: @moonboots: yeah, that's how i understood it. Maybe i was wrong....

Comment: yes Exit Code 1 needs to clarify a bit

Comment: I'm sorry if the question was unclear. My question was just as the title says: If materials are made in Blender or if they need to be made in another program. But as moonboots says, you make your materials in Blender, but you can as Marty Fouts says, also create them in another program. So this question is answered. But also every other comment was very, very helpful. Thank you very much again!

Comment: @ExitCode1 Yes, you can make your own textures inside Blender, either by procedural texture or by texture paint. Also, you could download texture to support your final goal. But, obviously, there are applications focused in 3d paint and material with more tools than Blender like Substance Designer, 3d Coat,Substance Painter and many more. Another way that some people use to make materials is with Real Textures made with HD Photos (Like a picture of your walls)

Comment: @Emir Got it, thank you very much!